# Unable to customise Samba in macOS Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, smb

I'm trying to customise the parameters of `/usr/sbin/smbd` in Big Sur. Most posts advise to tweak  `/etc/nsmb.conf`. However it seems that modifying `/etc/nsmb.conf` has no effect for me.

I even tried introducing a syntax error in `/etc/nsmb.conf`. Stopping `smbd` with
`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist` and checking that no `smbd` is alive. Finally restarting `smbd` with `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist`. But `/usr/sbin/smbd` doesn't pick up any syntax error and runs normally.

I tried looking for other `*smb*` files in `/etc` and `/Library` and found none. Could it be that Apple doesn't allow modifying the parameters of `smbd` in Big Sur? Or perhaps should I look at other files?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: According to `man smbd`, `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist` is used but shouldn't be updated manually. The string "nsmb.conf" doesn't even appear in `/usr/sbin/smbd`, are you looking at Linux documentation maybe?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to set/define?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @nohillside. I want to enable automatic home shares. See e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/share-ubuntu-home-directories-using-samba/; https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.htm. I am assuming I need to edit `nsmb.conf`. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204021 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7453680 where they edit `nsmb.conf` for different purposes.

Comment: `nsmb.conf` is used for client-side configurations, `smbd` is handling the server side. Which role does your Mac have in the setup?

Comment: Oh, I see. The Mac is the server. So I guess I should create a file `/etc/smb.conf`? I think I had read `/etc/smb.conf` had been moved to `/etc/nsmb.conf` somewhere but I can't find that page anymore.

Comment: If I understand your links above (and `man nsmb.conf`) corrrectly the file is not used for SMB server. You can configure sharing in the sharing pane in System Preferences

Comment: Thank you. I think you are correct. Then I conclude that you cannot adjust the parameters of a `smb.conf` file in OSX. Like you would do in Linux. There's also a `sharing` command line tool to create shares.

Comment: @User597 Making sure you are aware that macOS does not provide Samba and has not for many years, so using Samba documentation to configure it is probably a non-starter.

Comment: @MarcWilson that is obviously not true.

Comment: So you're going to waste everyone's time by claiming that Apple is still shipping Samba in 2021, is that right?  Samba is GPL3-licensed.  Apple removed Samba in 10.7 (2011).

Comment: Anyone know what they are using now, if not Samba? When I'm sharing a dir on Big Sur I see `smbd` process running. Or is this something else?

Comment: @Mint It's Apple's own implementation of the server side of the SMB protocol

Answer (score -1):

See the comments above from @nohillside and @Marc Wilson. Samba cannot be configured in OSX as you would do in Linux. Thanks @nohillside and @Marc Wilson.

Comment: That's not really true. If you download and run Samba on MacOS, you can configure it the same way as you would in Linux. However, as mentioned in the comments above, MacOS doesn't include Samba anymore, and has its own implementation of the SMB protocol. Unsurprisingly, since it's not using Samba, you can't configure it the same way you would configure Samba.